# Tracking A/B test impact in Google Analytics

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics

When running A/B Tests using the ExactTarget A/B test module, is there a way that the UTM campaign name can be automatically edited to reflect whether it was part of the A or B test?

The problem I'm having is:

I create one email and tag links throughout with "utm_campaign=pretty_princess_sale" and run it through the A/B test module based on Subject Line.  In Google Analytics, all conversions from users who received either subject line will fall under the campaign "pretty_princess_sale" without regard to whether they received Subject Line A or Subject Line B.

Is there a way that running tests via ET's A/B module will automatically amend the utm_campaign tag to reflect whether recipient received A or B? Ie, links for all recipients who receive Subject A will be automatically retagged as "utm_campaign=pretty_princess_sale_Agroup" and "utm_campaign=pretty_princess_sale_Bgroup".

Or is my only choice to create two separate emails with different UTM tags and send one in the A group and one in the B group?

Comment: I don't have any code for this, but you can always add some amp script to your links, and set a content area to also be A/B with a variable that is the tagging. Side note - do you have `Additional_Email_Attributes` turned on?  You can get an analytics connector to allow these to be added through out your email instead of manually.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific feature that I am aware of in the A/B Testing.  what you can do is set your `utm_campaign` to be the following AMPscript -

```
SET @utm = CONCAT("utm_campaign=pretty_princess_sale_", @testgroup)
```

And then what ever portion of the A/B test you are using, set the `@testgroup` variable.  You will need to play around with the order of things to get it all to work together, but this is completely doable.